# How can I add tabs to code sections?

Tags: support

Usually I use spaces to format code. But `make` in particular requires tabs in some parts of makefiles. How can I enter a tab in markdown such actual tabs are printed in the code section of my answer?

Comment: Why is this necessary? Why can't you just use spaces?

Comment: @CodyGray: `make` explicitly requires tabs. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2131227/789750) for an explanation.

Comment: Okay, I'm not debating that. I don't understand why code needs to be 100% copy-pastable. Make users know that it requires tabs.

Comment: @CodyGray: A makefile with spaces is a pretty subtle bug. I've been bitten by it before, and while I did include a warning I think it would be better to have both the warning and correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a very elegant solution (you lose syntax highlighting), but you can use a `<pre>` block and the HTML character entity `&#9;` for this.

E.g, the following:

```
<pre>
clean:
&#9;-rm -f $(EXE) $(EXE).a *.o
</pre>
```

renders as:

```
clean:
	-rm -f $(EXE) $(EXE).a *.o
```